# Microphone is too quiet on pc but fine on capture card

Tags: audio

I recently got a new microphone for my capture card because my current one is not compatible. Before using it with the capture card I tested it out on my pc, and I noticed that when I record, even when the levels are set to 100, it is way to quiet to hear. I then tried it on my capture card, and it sounds fine there, the only problems are on the pc. My other headset doesn't have this problem, just the new one. When I turn on the microphone boost, it gets slightly louder, but i can also hear lots of static. If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, please tell me. If it is of any significance, the new one uses 3.5mm jacks for both the headphones and the microphone, while my other one uses a usb connection for the headphones, and a 3.5mm jack for the mic. The old one is an Afterglow, and the new one is a Corsair.

Comment: Are you sure your adjusting the correct devices sound levels?  Your 3.5mm headphones won't appear as a device, this means you will have to  use the software that handles the configuration of the sound device instead.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your PC is expecting [line-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) input. Unless your microphone has an amplifier and thus a power source of some kind (including batteries), it is likely providing only mic-level input.

Possibly your old microphone had an amplifier (powered by the USB connection) and thus was providing a line-level signal. Your capture card presumably has an amplifier and thus can take mic-level input. The way round this is to connect your microphone to a sound card (either external, such as a Griffin iMic, or internal (your capture card?)) that is capable of receiving mic-level input.

There *may* be a way to set your PC's sound card firmware to a mic-level mode, but you would need to research your particular model. Otherwise, despite using the same physical 3.5mm jack interface, your microphone simply isn't compatible with the line-in port on your PC.